# gazebo5 specular in material does not work?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

this is my sdf file.

and  I expect my ball would reflect blue specular light

but nothing happened,It just appears whole dark

what am  I doing wrong??

thanks!

```
<model name='socket'>
    <pose> 0 0 0 0 0 0 </pose>
    <link name="link">
        <collision name="collision">
            <geometry>
                <sphere>
                    <radius>0.1</radius>
                </sphere>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <visual name="visual">
            <material>
                <ambient>0 0 0 1</ambient>
                <diffuse>0 0 0 1</diffuse>
                <specular>0 0 1 1</specular>
            </material>
            <geometry>
                <sphere>
                    <radius>0.1</radius>
                </sphere>
            </geometry>
        </visual>
    </link>
</model>
```

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15087/gazebo5-specular-in-material-does-not-work-!/) by [Zheng yo chen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/800/zheng-yo-chen/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 80 on 2016-12-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I don't think you're doing anything wrong, this seems to be a bug in Gazebo. I could reproduce the problem in gazebo7. Ticketed an issue for it:

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2120/specular-material-not-working

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1